# Como limitar e exibir a quantidade de caracteres de um JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Tenho uma janela de cadastro de fornecedores, e gostaria de inserir um `jTextArea` para que o usuário tenha a opção de digitar alguma observação sobre o fornecedor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é que, limite a quantidade de caracteres a ser digitado e mostre encima do `jTextArea` a quantidade que resta e quantos caracteres foram digitados.

Como posso fazer isso? Estou usando o NetBeans e no banco o campo que vou armazenar essas informações é tipo *TEXT*, `MySQL`.

Comment: [Isso aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13864001/5524514) é exatamente o que você precisa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conforme demonstrado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864001/5524514) no  SOEn, você pode fazer isso usando a classe [**`DocumentFilter`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).

Alterei o exemplo da resposta usando uma `JTextArea`, mas o efeito é o mesmo, afinal, `JTextField` e `JTextArea` são ambos campos de texto. Adicionei comentários em alguns pontos que achei relevantes do código também:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LimitarTextAreaTest extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private DefaultStyledDocument doc;
    private JLabel remaningLabel = new JLabel();

    public LimitarTextAreaTest() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 15);
        doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();

       //aqui é atribuido um filtro ao DefaultStyledDocument, é esta classe que vai
       //limitar o número máximo de caracteres, basta alterar o 500
       //para o valor maximo desejado
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentSizeFilter(500));
        //neste trecho, foi sobrescrito um DocumentListener,
        //que monitora alterações dentro do campo de texto
        //sempre que uma alteração for realizada, será invocado
        //o método updateCount(), que vai atualizar o numero
        //de caracteres restantes
        doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateCount();
            }
        });
        //finalmente o DefaultStyledDocument foi
        //atribuido ao seu campo de texto
        textArea.setDocument(doc);
        //insere o valor inicial restante
        updateCount();

        add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(remaningLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
    }

    private void updateCount() {
        remaningLabel.setText((500 - doc.getLength()) + " caracteres restantes");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LimitarTextAreaTest().setVisible(true);
    }

    //esta classe que faz a limitação de caracteres
    class DocumentSizeFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        int maxCharacters;
        boolean DEBUG = false;

        public DocumentSizeFilter(int maxChars) {
            maxCharacters = maxChars;
        }

        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offs,
                String str, AttributeSet a)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("in DocumentSizeFilter's insertString method");
            }

            //Isto rejeita novas inserções de caracteres se
            //a string for muito grande. Outra opção seria
            //truncar a string inserida, de forma que seja
            //adicionado somente o necessário para atingir
            //o limite máximo permitido
            if((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= maxCharacters) {
                super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
            } else {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        }

        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offs,
                int length,
                String str, AttributeSet a)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("in DocumentSizeFilter's replace method");
            }
            //Isto rejeita novas inserções de caracteres se
            //a string for muito grande. Outra opção seria
            //truncar a string inserida, de forma que seja
            //adicionado somente o necessário para atingir
            //o limite máximo permitido
            if((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() - length) <= maxCharacters) {
                super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
            } else {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Código acima funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apenas salientando que a classe `DocumentSizeFilter` foi retirada de um dos exemplos da documentação oficial, cujo link se encontra [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextComponentDemoProject/src/components/DocumentSizeFilter.java).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela força... Encaixou como uma luva.

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, teria que criar um evento com o jTextArea? Tipo quando clicasse pra digitar alguma coisa começasse a contar?

Comment: @Valdecir bom, você só precisa setar um `DocumentListener ` e a classe  `DocumentSizeFilter ` na sua jtextarea(copie da resposta e salve num arquivo separado pro seu código ficar mais organizado) como foi feito no codigo. E também você precisa adicionar na sua classe o método `updateCount()`, é ele quem atualiza a informação. Na imagem, logo abaixo da jtextArea tem um JLabel de nome `remaningLabel`, substitua pelo seu componente que quer que apareça a mensagem de contagem de caracteres restantes.

Comment: Muito bom cara!! Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Excelente exemplo, ainda adicionou um contador e um GIF, parabéns!